# Reset shell password

Tags: command-line, password-recovery, reset

I know my user password. I am the only user on computer. Latest version of Ubuntu.I do not remember the password for shell terminal.My user password does not work. How do I reset shell password?

Comment: What shell password are we talking here and why is the password needed?

Comment: I know my password to open and run computer. I do not remember the password to use sudo in Terminal.  Basically I can't use Terminal I am trying to reset password in Terminal so I can use it.. I think 1 answer below will help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgotten root password in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031379/forgotten-root-password-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have changed your [GNOME Keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring) password and it doesn't match to your user's password that is used within the shell. In result you can't use `sudo`, because you don't remember this password.

If this is true, you can follow the next steps to run your system in the recovery mode and change the system user password:

- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the boot to open the Grub menu.
- Choice **Advanced Options for Ubuntu**, then choice the item that contains **(recovery mode)** at the end.
- In the next menu choice **root** - **Drop to root shell prompt** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the next question.
- Remount the file system with read/write permissions:

  ```
  mount -o remount,rw /
  ```
- Set a new user password (where `<USERNAME>` is the actual user name):

  ```
  passwd <USERNAME>
  ```
- Restart the system. Type `exit` and in the menu choice **resume** - **Resume normal boot**. Or just type `reboot`.